# Python Sum individual integers

Tags: python

I want to make a python app that sums the numbers of a birthdate.

```
day = raw_input("What day were you born?")
month = raw_input("What month were you born?")
year = raw_input("What year were you born?")
day = int(day)
month = int(month)
year = int(year)
```

Let's say that someone was born on 12/10/1928; how could I make this app to sum it like this: 1+2+1+0+1+9+2+8?
This is done on Python 2.7

*PS: I forgot to mention that my final result must be a one digit number so for example in the sum above the result is 24 but that number must sum itself so 2 + 4 = 6, being 6 the final answer.*

Comment: Well, first, don't bother converting those inputs to integer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of casting them as integers, add them as strings and then map each character as an integer and find the sum:

```
day = raw_input("What day were you born?")
month = raw_input("What month were you born?")
year = raw_input("What year were you born?")
print sum(map(int, day+month+year))
```

If you want to keep adding the digits until you arrive at a one-digit number, use a loop:

```
day = raw_input("What day were you born?")
month = raw_input("What month were you born?")
year = raw_input("What year were you born?")
num = day+month+year
while len(num) > 1:
    num = str(sum(map(int, num)))
print num
```

Comment: As in the example above the final result would be 24, but i want the final result to be a one digit number. How could i add 24 individually (i.e. 2+4)?

Comment: @NicolasMoran - You would use a loop to keep adding the digits.

Answer (score 0):

Following function would provide output as single digit sum for any input number. Just typecast your day, month, year, add them up and provide input to following function.

```
def get_sum_as_single_digit(digit):
    final_sum=0
    while digit>0:
        mod = digit%10
        digit = digit/10
        final_sum = final_sum + mod
    if final_sum>9:
        return get_single_digit_sum(final_sum)
    else:
        return final_sum
```